# Ardu-IMU sending data to Arduino

Tags: c, binary, arduino

I've just bought an [ArduIMU](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1116368) and I'm trying to send data to Arduino. I customized the preferences, here they are.

```
#define BOARD_VERSION 2 // 1 For V1 and 2 for V2
#define GPS_CONNECTION 0 // 0 for GPS pins, 1 for programming pins
// GPS Type Selection - Note Ublox or MediaTek is recommended.  Support for NMEA is limited.
#define GPS_PROTOCOL 1    // 1 - NMEA,  2 - EM406,  3 - Ublox, 4 -- MediaTek  
// Enable Air Start uses Remove Before Fly flag - connection to pin 6 on ArduPilot 
#define ENABLE_AIR_START 0  //  1 if using airstart/groundstart signaling, 0 if not
#define GROUNDSTART_PIN 8    //  Pin number used for ground start signal (recommend 10 on v1 and 8 on v2 hardware)
/*Min Speed Filter for Yaw drift Correction*/
#define SPEEDFILT 2 // >1 use min speed filter for yaw drift cancellation (m/s), 0=do not use speed filter
/*For debugging propurses*/
#define PRINT_DEBUG 0   //Will print Debug messages
//OUTPUTMODE=1 will print the corrected data, 0 will print uncorrected data of the gyros (with drift), 2 will print accelerometer only data
#define OUTPUTMODE 1
#define PRINT_DCM 1     //Will print the whole direction cosine matrix
#define PRINT_ANALOGS 1 //Will print the analog raw data
#define PRINT_EULER 1   //Will print the Euler angles Roll, Pitch and Yaw
#define PRINT_GPS 0     //Will print GPS data
#define PRINT_BINARY 1  //Will print binary message and suppress ASCII messages (above)
#define PERFORMANCE_REPORTING 0  //Will include performance reports in the binary output ~ 1/2 min
#define MAGNETIC_DECLINATION 2.15    // corrects magnetic bearing to true north
```

OK, I set the binary mode to "1" instead of the ASCII one ("0"). How can I read the data sent by ArduIMU to Arduino and decode it?

***SOLUTION:***

Check my blog, I wrote an article on how to read binary data from ArduIMU on Arduino

[How to read binary data from ArduIMU - Codesigns.it](http://codesigns.altervista.org/blog/2010/10/02/how-to-read-binary-data-from-arduimu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to read binary data from ArduIMU](http://codesigns.altervista.org/blog/2010/10/02/how-to-read-binary-data-from-arduimu/) :)

Comment: @fran I know! Just thought I'd answer the question since noone else had.